# What does it mean: JSONDecode Error: Extra data?

Tags: python

I am trying to work with the huge JSON file and especially to see what keys it has, but I get the error `JSONDecode Error:Extra data`.
Can someone recommend to me how can I read it and see what keys it has?

```
import json
with open('/Volumes/MagaCOV_Jan_2020/1_2020_1.json', 'r') as f:
    distros_dict = json.load(f)
distros_dict.keys()
```

Comment: This might be an issue with your JSON. Can you edit the question to include your JSON?

Comment: There is usually more information than that in the error message — such as the line number or file offset where the problem was encounter. If so, you can use that to look at the file in a text editor and see what is the issue. There are also online online JSON formatter/validator and "lint" utilities that you could theoretically use, by that may not be a viable option with a huge file.